# Can the default font be changed?

Tags: customization

I have been playing with the settings for the text object recently, and every time I add a new text object, I need to change the font to my favorite one. (*Eurostile LT ExtendedTwo*) Is there any way to change the default font so I do not need to change it every time I add a new text object?

Example:

[image]

Comment: You are X-27, disguised as a Radish :D The font and the blue gave it away.

Comment: Hey, I needed to do something for April Fool's day. Besides, you also could have looked at any of my questions which are almost All about the BGE :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible without the internal editing of the Blender source. I would recommend submitting a feature request for this. This feature could be very useful and should not be hard to implement. Someone could potentially create a patch that adds that ability as well.