# Can you change the shader and font settings as a new default?

Tags: materials

I was wondering if you know how to change the default settings in Blender? When I change the "Viewport Shading" to render by pushing "Shift Z", then push "Shift Z" again to go back to "Solid", is it possible to have it go back to "Material" instead? I have tried looking up how to do this but nothing came up.

[image: Change Material to Default]

Also when I load a font, the view always goes to "Short List". Is there a way to change the default setting to "Thumbnails" so that every time I open a font it stays on "Thumbnails"?

[image: Change Font to Thumbnails as Default]

I know its probably not a big deal clicking one extra button but it would be a lot easier for my workflow. Would you know anything about this? Thanks!

Comment: You can turn on the pie menu addon in the user interface and that would probably solve your first question. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/UI/Pie_Menus

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27979/can-the-default-font-be-changed

Answer (score 1):

For the first question about the keyboard shortcuts

1. Go to Blender User preferences window [Ctrl+Alt+U] under the "Input Tab"
2. Search for "Context toggle values" in the search field.
3. Scroll down to the "3D View" category
4. You should see three entries by default for [Z] [Alt+Z] and [Shift+Z]
   key combinations.
5. Expand each of them and change the strings in the "Value" fields to whatever you want.
6. In you case change the [Shift+Z] to toggle between "MATERIAL" and "RENDERED"